# Help installing Reaver?

Tags: wireless, software-installation

I am now trying to install reaver but when I entered:

```
wget http://reaver-wps.googlecode.com/files/reaver-1.4.tar.gz
```

I got a 404 error so I tried downloading it manually and putting it on the desktop but when I enter:

```
tar -xzvf reaver-1.4.tar.gz
```

I get an error saying that there is no such file / destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods to install Reaver:

**1. From the Ubuntu Repositories:**

Simply run the following in a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install reaver
```

and this should be enough to get you going. You could also use the Software Center or even my old friend Synaptic.

**2. Compile from source:**

If you wish to build your own copy of Reaver here is a single code block that should successfully download, compile, package and install Reaver under Xenial Xerus. You only really need to do this if you wish to patch the source or add some extra options to the package...

Just copy the whole code box below and paste it into a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall && \
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libpcap0.8-dev && \
mkdir $HOME/Desktop/reaver_build && cd $HOME/Desktop/reaver_build && \
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/\
code.google.com/reaver-wps/reaver-1.4.tar.gz && \
tar xvf reaver-1.4.tar.gz && cd reaver-1.4/src && \
./configure && make && \
sudo checkinstall --pakdir "$HOME/Desktop/reaver_build" --backup=no --deldoc=yes \
                  --pkgname reaver --pkgversion "1.4" --fstrans=no \
                  --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --default
```

Depends which way you want to go....

Comment: okay so i got it running but now i have issues with the "wash" commande its not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

You are not in the same directory, where you have downloaded the reaver.tar file.
you should try

```
cd Desktop
```

Or you can start from begining

Download Reaver from [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/reaver-wps/downloads)

```
cd Downloads
tar xvfz reaver-1.4.tar.gz
```